# how to make emacs gui behave like guake/tilda/yakuake

Tags: fullscreen

Emacs newbie here. I simply want to setup Emacs GUI to toggle hide/show(visibility) just like we see in guake, tilda or yakuake terminals. for example I have am working with Emacs within GUI and I have a browser window behind it, I want to hide Emacs with a shortcut(e.g F12) and then I will see my browser and will be able to interact with it and other windows, then again press F12 and I will have my Emacs GUI back. If it is not possible from inside Emacs, can I do this from desktop(running KDE 5.13).

Comment: Please explain in more detail what "toggle hide/show(visibility)" means for people that do not know guake, tilda, or yakuake. Note that `C-z` is bound to the command `suspend-frame` which hides the active emacs frame.

Comment: @Tobias thanks for your comment. I updated the question to better explain the question.

Comment: Please try `C-z`, i.e., hold the control key down and press the z-key. The emacs frame will be hidden. Pressing `C-z` again reveals the emacs frame again. Is that what you want? Note, I've tested that under Windows10/cygwin. Don't know wether it works under X11/KDE. It should work.

Comment: @Tobias I tried and it didn't work. I don't think that you will be able to interact with the browser after `C-z`. I want the GUI to go completely away and let me interact with other windows, and then then bring it back with focus on the emacs GUI.

Comment: You wrote in your comment: "I don't think that you will be able to interact with the browser after `C-z`. I want the GUI to go completely away and let me interact with other windows". But you wrote in your question: "I want to hide Emacs with a shortcut(e.g F12) and then I will see my browser, then again press F12 and I will see my Emacs GUI". `C-z` does exactly what you wrote in your question (at least under Win10/cygwin) but not what you wrote in your comment. I think you should update your question with the relevant text from your comment.

Comment: @Tobias you are absolutely right. I did update my question again.

Comment: I really do think it's more of a window manager question...

Comment: @manandearth, it is likely related to window manager, but since the mentioned terminal have built-in support for this feature( and since it is such a useful feature), I thought maybe Emacs have it built in.

Comment: If Emacs (or your terminal for that matter) does not have focus in the window manager, then Emacs has no idea if you have pressed F12 (or anything else).  You would need to tell your window manager that pressing F12 should make it look for an Emacs frame and do the appropriate thing.  I would guess that the terminals you mention are installing some kind of similar support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this script (I found it, it is in Russian):

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################################################################
# This script will toggle minimize/activate first window with specified class
# If window not found program will be launched
#
# window class can be found with next programs:
#   wmctrl -x -l
#   xprop
# No credit taken.......... Cannot read the original.....
# Found on http://blog.sokolov.me/2014/06/20/linuxx11-toggle-window-minimizemaximize/
# in Russian :) but works when adjusting the wrapping.
######################################################################################################
NEEDED_WINDOW_CLASS="emacs.Emacs"
LAUNCH_PROGRAM="emacs"
######################################################################################################
NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX=`wmctrl -x -l | grep ${NEEDED_WINDOW_CLASS} | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1`
NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC=$((${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX}))
if [ -z "${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX}" ]; then
${LAUNCH_PROGRAM}
else
echo "Found window ID:${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}(0x${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_HEX})"
ACIVE_WINDOW_DEC=`xdotool getactivewindow`
if [ "${ACIVE_WINDOW_DEC}" == "${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}" ]; then
    xdotool windowminimize ${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}
else
    xdotool windowactivate ${NEEDED_WINDOW_WINDOW_ID_DEC}
    fi
fi
```

Assign the script to a hotkey.

Comment: and how can I assign the script to a hotkey  ?

Comment: I confirm that this works after install xdotool and wmctrl

Comment: @miladzahedi In Gnome. Go to System Settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts.
Click on + to add a custom shortcut. Name it anything.
Make sure your script has executable permission.

Answer (score 0):

I found two Emacs packages for this, one if [yequake](https://github.com/alphapapa/yequake) which does exactly what you asked for (makes the Emacs GUI to work like you want):

[image]

and there is [equake](https://gitlab.com/emacsomancer/equake) which does this for shells of Emacs:

[image]

Both have their own merits and potentials. I personally would rather use yequake as I would like to be able to see images and PDFs in my Emacs, and I don't heavily use eshell/term/ansi-term. Also there is Yakuake in KDE which is an amazing terminal and does everything I want.